# Multiple sensor data in same page in qt/qml application

Tags: qt, qml

I am developing and Qt/ qml application which runs on a limited resource device. App displays instant data of multiple sensors. Every sensor sends data periodically with different frequencies. Their frequency is much frequency than device can refresh Frame. Currently I am registering every sensors data to qml side as q_property and reassign their value every time one of the sensor sends data which is more frequent that frame can be refreshed. What I want to do is assign properties onlu before refreshing Frame. What is the best way in this situation? I researched about before rendering function of qquickwindow, but couldnt handle it.

Comment: your question is not so clear. What data? Is your sensor logic implemented in the C++ part? Probably you have to implement a [slignal-slot](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html) mechanism to inform the QML GUI from C++ code or vice versa.

Comment: Sorry about unclearness of question, tried to be explanatory. Sensors are temperature, humidity and pressure. Sensor logic implemented in C++. Yes I have a signal-slot mechanism from every sensor.cpp file to mu pages qml file. Every time data comes from the sensor I notify qml side and refresh Frame. Problem is this frequency is very high than device can refresh.

Comment: collect your data and notify the QML side periodically using some timer.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with sensor data i would suggest that you delay/time the input on the c++/sensor side rather than on the GUI side.

e.g. i had data from joysticks on an Arduino that would refresh faster than every 0.01 sec. i than implemented a delay of 0.1 or 0.2 seconds on the arduino/hardware side and send all data from all devices in the same interval. I am guessing from the type of data you are collecting that its not even necessary that it refreshes so fast? So maybe just give it a 5+ second delay? QML than can refresh every 5 seconds.

if thats not an option for you i would also suggest like folibis to use a timer thats sets the new values in an interval.